# PHP 5.6.8 cerficate verification failure

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Platform: Ubuntu14.04 + xampp 5.5.24 \ 5.6.8 + openssl

Error message while sending an email from phpmailer:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Sentrifugo_2.0/install/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php on line 270
```

on few blogs i have read that we can allow insecure connections via the SMTPOptions and achieve it by subclassing the SMTP class with the following:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
)
);
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can support in confirming where should i be configuring this as i have already searched the class.smtp.php and class.phpmailer.php files but couldnt find verify_peer .

Also, on line 270 i found the following code in class.smtp.php:

```
/**
 * Initiate a TLS (encrypted) session.
 * @access public
 * @return bool
 */
public function startTLS()
{
    if (!$this->sendCommand('STARTTLS', 'STARTTLS', 220)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Begin encrypted connection
    if (!stream_socket_enable_crypto(
        $this->smtp_conn,
        true,
        STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT
    )) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please suggest - thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

This is covered in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

You're getting things a bit mixed up. In older versions of PHPMailer, you could only fix this by subclassing to pass in the ssl settings, but now you can do it via the code you posted:

```php
$mail->SMTPOptions = [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
];
```

This sets the `SMTPOptions` property of PHPMailer, which is passed to the `stream_socket_client` function. There is no `verify_peer` property in PHPMailer itself - it's a setting within the [ssl properties of stream contexts in PHP](https://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php).

When `startTLS()` is called, the stream has already had the context attached to it, so when `stream_socket_enable_crypto` gets called, it will make use of the ssl properties set on the stream when it was created.

Remember that when you choose to go this route of suppressing certificate verification, you are compromising your security.

Comment: Thanks Synchro for the information - but being a noob Can you please also assist as where do i have to enter the above SMTPOptions code - I meant in which file , which function and how that function should look like after making changes? thanks

Comment: That change goes in your own code, where you're using PHPMailer from. `$mail` is just the name of the PHPMailer instance you're using.

Comment: Synchro - to add - i am trying to make Sentrifugo application send an email using phpmailer and our emails are hosted with office 365. i even tried with gmail and yahoo account but still the error message is the same.   :(

Comment: Synchro -- can you please have a look into the source code of Sentrifugo https://github.com/sapplica/sentrifugo/blob/master/install/step4.php  can you please confirm if i have to add the SMTPOptions line into their source code page here as i can see at line 165 they have configured similar parameters. thanks

Comment: If youre' still getting the same error after setting that, make sure you're using a recent version of PHPMailer, preferably 5.2.10.

Comment: In that code, you'd insert the above fix at around line 175.

Comment: Sentrifugio is using an old version of PHPMailer (5.2.7). They should really be pulling their classes from composer, not including them in their own repo like this. You will need to replace the PHPMailer folder in the Sentrifugio data folder with a new download from github.

Comment: I created an issue on github for them to update their copy of PHPMailer.

Comment: Thanks synchro for your information - i have forwarded your comment to them in order to resolve their issue. :-) i will confirm you as soon as its working for me.

Answer (score -1):

**Warning**

Using PHPMailer with two different accounts, on two different domains, both passwords were stolen.

The code

```
require 'php_libraries/php_mailer/Exception.php';
require 'php_libraries/php_mailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'php_libraries/php_mailer/SMTP.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "from@domain.com";
$mail->Password = "password";

//From
$mail->setFrom('from@domain.com', 'No Reply');

//To
$mail->addAddress("to@domain.com", "user");
$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$mail->addAttachment("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\oasis\\excelReport\\test.xlsx");
$mail->Body = "body";

$mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true));

if (!$mail->send())
{
    $result="error";
}
else
{
    $result="ok";
}

echo $result;
```