# PHPMailer Not Sending to Outlook.com

Tags: php, security, email, outlook

**Background:**

I have been using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send emails through my website, but lately, certain people have not been able to receive my emails.

I tested the issue, and it seems like emails cannot be sent to emails on Outlook.com.

On the other hand, the emails can be sent to all other email services that I have tested including Gmail and Zoho.

I have tried using `$mail->SMTPAuth = true` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698946/4283581)) and the `$mail->SMTPOptions` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30803024/4283581)) workarounds that I have found as suggestions from elsewhere.

`$mail->send()` seems to return `true`, and I do not receive any errors from `$mail->ErrorInfo`.

Regardless, the emails that I send will not send to Outlook.com email addresses.

**Is there some sort of security feature that I need to add to allow sending to Outlook email addresses?**

Please let me know if there is any other information that I can provide. Any help would be appreciated!

**PHPMailer Code:**

```
require 'Classes/mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$recipient = $_POST['email_address'];
$recipient = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', $recipient );
$recipient = trim( $recipient, ';' );

$recipient_array = explode( ';', $recipient );

$subject = $_POST['email_subject'];
$body = nl2br( $_POST['email_message'] );

$footer =   '<br />
            <table id="email_footer">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        EMAIL SIGNATURE
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <hr />
                        FOOTER IMAGE
                        <hr />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:15px">
                        ADDRESS
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>';

$attachment = 'pdf/' . $_POST['attachment'];

$mail->isSMTP();                                // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'localhost';                      // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'webmaster@example.com';      // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password123';                // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                      // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = "25";                             // TCP port to connect to

$mail->SMTPOptions = array (
    'ssl' => array (
        'verify_peer'       => false,
        'verify_peer_name'  => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$mail->setFrom( 'webmaster@example.com', 'Business Name' );
$mail->addReplyTo( 'webmaster@example.com', 'Business Name' );

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $recipient_array ); $i++ )
{
    $mail->addAddress( $recipient_array[$i] );
}

$mail->addAddress( 'example@zoho.com' );                            // Forwards to local email for records (cannot send email to own server [workaround])

$mail->Subject = $subject;                                          // Subject
$mail->Body = $body . '<br />' . $footer;                           // Body of email
$mail->AddAttachment( $attachment, 'purchase-order.pdf' );          // Attach a file

$mail->isHTML( true );                                              // Set email format to HTML

if( !$mail->send() )
{
    echo 'Message could not be sent.<br />';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

**Thank you for your time.**

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Code Review! This is a site for where people review finished and complete code for improvements, not for fixing broken code, unfortunately. You might be able to find your solution on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My best guess is that the problem has nothing to do with your actual code, and instead the email is being blocked/filtered by the Outlook.com mail gateway. Are you using DKIM or SPF?

Comment: I mean, as far as I can see, you're having an issue with broken code, as you have stated that you can't send mail to accounts with Outlook. It seems to me that want to fix your code, that's why I redirected you to Stack Overflow. Your comment and your actual question seem dissonant, you should reflect that you want a review instead of fixing a problem in your question body.

Comment: Do you want to know why email is not working?  Or a review of the code?  As written, it seems that you want to know why email is not working.  If you edit out those parts of the question, this would be on-topic.  As is, this would make more sense on Server Fault or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume your code it works correctly.
I used to try to send an invitation to friends and met quite similar issue with OUTLOOK.

Here are a couple of thing to consider.

1. **Every email provider has different filtering | blocking policy**

   Some script will be fine to send email to some email provider, but not to others.
   Usually, email provider will block|filter issued email account first, if they feel too much spamming from certain IP, then they will block the IP eventually.
2. **Don't be looked like spammer**

   Change "webmaster@example.com". Maybe it will work a few times, but eventually it can be blocked.
   Recommend your to create test email account to send test email, if your script works good, then use REAL email account.
   You may use email which supports SMTP for test. Otherwise, you would be better to have proper domain in your machine
   **Do not send to too many recipients at once**, it looks like spamming, right ? Better one by one, and please **use slightly different email Subject**, if you can.
   **Do not send too quickly,** use sleep method for seconds and send another email. Otherwise, some email provider think you as DoS attacker
3. **Look into mailer error message**

   YOUR MACHINE <=>(YOUR SIDE SECURITY LAYER)<=>(EMAIL PROVIDER SECURITY LAYER)<=> EMAIL SERVER
   They communicates and give you message back.
   In your case, you do not receive any errors from $mail->ErrorInfo,
   **Case 1. If you sent email to outlook successfully before:**
        I presume, your request might not reach email server. (I guess you were blocked). Please contact OUTLOOK.
   **Case 2. If you never send email to outlook successfully before:**
   Please check email configuration or your firewall and network setting etc.

Hope this will give you brief guideline.